# error al pasar una funcion de una clase como anonima a metodo set_error_handler en php

Tags: php, poo

estoy haciendo un codigo para almacenar los warning y e_notice de php en un archivo de texto, para eso ocupo el metodo set_error_handler  que permite pasar como parametro una funcion,

al tener la funcion a fuera de una clase funciona bien pero al tener la funcion dentro de la clase genera error.

***mi pregunta es, las funciones de una clase pueden ser pasadas como funciones anonimas,en ese caso cual es la sintaxis.***

```
 //INTENTE SIN COMILLAS
  set_error_handler($obj->logPhp(), E_WARNING);
  set_error_handler($obj->logPhp(), E_NOTICE);
```

**Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function conexion::logPhp(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoEncuesta\prueba_print.php on line 43 and exactly 5 expected in**

archivo donde llamo la funcion de la clase

```
<?php
require_once 'clases/conexion.php';
$array= array("item1"=>1,"item2"=>2);


$obj=new Conexion();
set_error_handler($obj->logPhp(), E_WARNING);
set_error_handler($obj->logPhp(), E_NOTICE);

try {
  $valor=$array["este indice no existe"];
} catch (Exception $e) {

}

?>
```

clase conexion solo colocare el metodo que se ocupa

```
 function logPhp($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline,$errcontext){
  $string="";
  switch ($errno) {
    case E_WARNING:
             $string.= "Hay un WARNING.<br />\n";
             $string.="El warning es: ". $errstr ."<br />\n";
             $string.="El fichero donde se ha producido el warning es: ". $errfile ."<br />\n";
             $string.="La línea donde se ha producido el warning es: ". $errline ."<br />\n";
             /* No ejecutar el gestor de errores interno de PHP, hacemos que lo pueda procesar un try catch */
             $myfile = fopen(dirname(__DIR__)."/temporal/errores_php.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
             fwrite($myfile, "\n \n \n $trace \n". $string);
             fclose($myfile);

             return true;
             break;

         case E_NOTICE:
             $string.= "Hay un E_NOTICE.<br />\n";
             $string.="El e_notice es: ". $errstr ."<br />\n";
             $string.="El fichero donde se ha producido el e_notice es: ". $errfile ."<br />\n";
             $string.="La línea donde se ha producido el e_notice es: ". $errline ."<br />\n";

             /* No ejecutar el gestor de errores interno de PHP, hacemos que lo pueda procesar un try catch */
             $myfile = fopen(dirname(__DIR__)."/temporal/errores_php.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
             fwrite($myfile, "\n \n \n $trace \n". $string);
             fclose($myfile);
             return true;
             break;

         default:
             /* Ejecuta el gestor de errores interno de PHP */
             return false;
             break;
         }

}
```

por ultimo cabe destacar que la Version de php es 7.2.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes. Primero, el error que indicas:

```
set_error_handler( $obj->logPhp( ), E_WARNING );
set_error_handler( $obj->logPhp( ), E_NOTICE );
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function `conexion::logPhp()`, 0 passed and exactly 5 expected.

Fíjate que **estás llamando a la función**: `$obj->logPhp( )`, al llevar **los paréntesis**, es **una llamada en si misma**. Y tu función **requiere** 5 argumentos, y la estás llamando **sin ninguno**. De ahí el error.

Ahora, lo que nos interesa. Primero, miramos la documentación de [`set_error_handler( )`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.set-error-handler.php):

> #### Descripción
>
> ```
> set_error_handler ( callable $error_handler [, int $error_types = E_ALL | E_STRICT ] ) : mixed<br>
> ```
>
> #### Parámetros
>
> *error_handler*
>   
>   Una llamada de retorno con la siguiente signatura:
>   `handler ( int $errno , string $errstr [, string $errfile [, int $errline [, array $errcontext ]]] ) : bool`

Vale, ya vemos que como primer parámetro requiere un [`callable`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.callable.php). Hacemos *click* en el enlace ...

> #### Pasar una función de llamada de retorno
>
> ...
>   Un método de un object instanciado se pasa **como un array que contiene un object en el índice 0 y el nombre del método en el índice 1**. Está permitido el acceso a métodos protegidos y privados desde dentro de una clase.

Y un poco mas abajo tenemos incluso un ejemplo. Siguiéndolo, hacemos:

```
$obj = new Conexion( );
set_error_handler( [ $obj, 'logPhp' ], E_WARNING );
set_error_handler( [ $obj, 'logPhp' ], E_NOTICE );
```

Un último punto. Según la documentación de `set_error_handler( )` vista al principio, la función `handler` **debería tener los últimos 3 argumentos opcionales**, mientras que tú has puesto los 5 obligatorios.

Deberías cambiar tu función, y comprobar si dichos argumentos han sido recibidos:

```
function logPhp( $errno, $errstr, $errfile = NULL, $errline = NULL ,$errcontext = NULL ) {
  $string="";
  switch( $errno ) {
  case E_WARNING:
    $string .= "Hay un WARNING.<br />\n";
    $string .= "El warning es: ". $errstr ."<br />\n";
    if( !is_null( $errfile ) ) $string .= "El fichero donde se ha producido el warning es: ". $errfile ."<br />\n";
    if( !is_null( $errline ) ) $string. = "La línea donde se ha producido el warning es: ". $errline ."<br />\n";
    $myfile = fopen( dirname( __DIR__ ) . "/temporal/errores_php.txt", "a" ) or die( "Unable to open file!" );
    fwrite( $myfile, "\n \n \n $trace \n". $string );
    fclose( $myfile );

    return true;
    break;
  ...
```

Y lo mismo con los demás `case`.

Comment: gracias me sirvio la respuesta.